# Inserting Regular Expressions into OpenRefine facets

Tags: regex, openrefine, grel

Working in OpenRefine I want to find word pairs where the second word is 'Street'.

I have a python regular expression which works for this but I can't get it to work in OpenRefine.

https://regex101.com/r/igjCuo/94 show the regex working

```
\w+(\s+Street)
```

My issue is that I am obviously not inserting the regex into OpenRefine correctly.

#### Testing

If I try

```
value.find("Street")
```

then all cells which contain the word correctly return.

[image]

However putting the regular expression into the same query doesn't work

[image]

I know that this is something basic about formatting the query but I am at a loss and would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not form a correct regex literal/string pattern and added extra double quotation marks.

You may use

```
value.find("\\w+\\s+Street")
value.find(/\w+\s+Street/)
```

Note you do not need a capturing group as you need to get whole matches.

See [OpenRefine 3.0 onwards](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/GREL-String-Functions#openrefine-30-onwards):

> NOTE: If `p` is a String then we compile it into a regex pattern, otherwise, If `p` is already a regex, then we just use that regex pattern. **NOTE: When supplying the regex pattern in string quotes, you will need to use escaping (double slashes)**